# How to send 2 mails simultaneously with drupal_mail()

Tags: emails

I want to send my order to my email, and also to my client's email.

I am sending an order placed on my website using this code:

```
function MYMODULE_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  order_mail_send($form_state['values']);
}
```

This is the `order_mail_send()` code:

```
function order_mail_send($form_values) {
  $module = 'shop';
  $key = 'key';
  $to = $form_values['email'];

  $language = language_default();
  $params = array();
  $from = NULL;
  $send = FALSE;
  $message = drupal_mail($module, $key, $to, $language, $params, $from, $send);
  $message2 = drupal_mail($module, $key, $from, $language, $params, $from, $send);

  $subject = 'Order Status';

  $message['subject'] = $subject;
  $message['body'] = array();

  $message['body'][] = "<h3>Your order: ".$form_values['first']." ".$form_values['last']."</h3>";

  // …

  // Retrieve the responsible implementation for this message.
  $system = drupal_mail_system($module, $key);


  // Format the message body.
  $message = $system->format($message);
  $message2 = $system->format($message2);

  // Send e-mail.
  $message['result'] = $system->mail($message);
  $message['result2'] = $system->mail($message2);


  if ($message['result'] && $message['result2'] == TRUE) {
    drupal_set_message(t('Your order has been sent. Thank you!'));
  }
  else {
    drupal_set_message(t('There was a problem sending your message and it was not sent.'), 'error');
  }
}
```

1. Now it sends the first email (`$message = $system->format($message);` but not the second one. How can I make it work?
2. How can I empy the cart values after sending the emails? The cart empties when I close the browser, but I want to delete it after sending as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use CC to send a copy to admin/yourself

 
`$message['headers']['CC'] = "foo@gmail.com"`

Comment: Seems that this will stop my emails to be send. It throws me an error.

Comment: As suggested by kiamlaluno, you need to change your code a bit , I suggest you have a look here for detailed explanation http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21examples%21email_example%21email_example.module/6 Click on view source

Answer (score 3):

Your code is not correct, as a module that calls [drupal_mail()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!mail.inc/function/drupal_mail/7) doesn't then call [drupal_mail_system()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!mail.inc/function/drupal_mail_system/7), but it implements [hook_mail()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_mail/7). An example of this hook implementation is [contact_mail()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21contact%21contact.module/function/contact_mail/7), which handles the emails sent from the Contact module in [contact_personal_form_submit()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!contact!contact.pages.inc/function/contact_personal_form_submit/7), and [contact_site_form_submit()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!contact!contact.pages.inc/function/contact_site_form_submit/7).

```
  // contact_site_form_submit()
  $values = $form_state['values'];
  $values['sender'] = $user;
  $values['sender']->name = $values['name'];
  $values['sender']->mail = $values['mail'];
  $values['category'] = contact_load($values['cid']);

  // Save the anonymous user information to a cookie for reuse.
  if (!$user->uid) {
    user_cookie_save(array_intersect_key($values, array_flip(array('name', 'mail'))));
  }

  // Get the to and from e-mail addresses.
  $to = $values['category']['recipients'];
  $from = $values['sender']->mail;

  // Send the e-mail to the recipients using the site default language.
  drupal_mail('contact', 'page_mail', $to, language_default(), $values, $from);

  // If the user requests it, send a copy using the current language.
  if ($values['copy']) {
    drupal_mail('contact', 'page_copy', $from, $language, $values, $from);
  }

  // Send an auto-reply if necessary using the current language.
  if ($values['category']['reply']) {
    drupal_mail('contact', 'page_autoreply', $from, $language, $values, $to);
  }
```

As also said from kantu, you can CC send the email to any other user that is not the receiver.

Comment: Hello kiamluno. I still don't understand what's wrong by using:  $message['result'] = $system->mail($message);
?

Comment: Modules sending an email never call `drupal_mail_system()`; as consequence, your code should not contain `$system->mail($message)`.

Comment: Thanks, I found this code snippet somewhere and I used it for system->format in order to format the body...I found your information very useful. I will format it using mimemail module now.

Comment: Hello @kiamluno, I managed to rewrite my code using your suggestion. Now I am using hook_mail() (tough I am not very convinced of its utility as long as I can compose my email body in hook_mail_submit).